# Custom Marker Properties in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

With the google map api, for every marker I create i want to have a custom property that will state more information about that location. Is it possible for me to add a custom property? Or do i have to make a separate class?

Maybe something like this?

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
            .title(title)
             .snippet(snippet)
            .customProperty1(true));
```

If I was to make a new class, code snippets would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: which type properties you actual want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create custom marker and add details in it.

you can pass information in title or snippet only and use it in your custom marker

```
mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_mapinfo, null); // my custom view

                // Getting the position from the marker
                //   LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
                TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
                TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

                // Setting the latitude
                tvLat.setText(arg0.getTitle());

                // Setting the longitude
                AppSession.setIconTypeface(tvLng);
                tvLng.setText(Html.fromHtml(arg0.getSnippet()));

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

layout_mapinfo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

how to pass value in titles and snippet and how to interprete it in your custom view is depended on your requirement.

hope this will help.

***Note : This snippet is for example purpose.***

Comment: Hmm I understand, however if snippet only accepts a string value, how do I add multiple properties in a snippet through an array or something. Could you provide  some samples for that?

Comment: Yes you can pass comma separated values in string and split it in array in adaptor.  Check how to convert string to array @J.Tey